# Holding the value of one select box when other select box change it's value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 select box running in a same page. One Select box name is "Select Month" and another is "Select Name", Now by default Select Month box holding value of a month like "May 2016" and by default Select Name box holding value of Select Name, so when I first change the Select name box value like "Michael", and change the Select Month Value month like "June 2016", then Select name box value "Michael" got disappear and change it's value to "Select Name" again. And it's because of there are many js files running on my site where this 2 select box is showing. And I won't be able to show all the lines of codes in here. All I want is that Select Name value will be Hold the value Name "Michael" (when I change it) irrespective of what is happening in Select Month box value field. And when I do opposite like first change select month and then change select name, then it's all fine. But not working when I first change select Name value and then change Select Month value. That time Name value isn't holding it's position. What I have tried add a onchange code in Client Name section and write down something in the script so that it can work. But nothing is happening.

```
<div class="monthNavigator">
<label for="imonth">Select Month: </label>
<select id="imonth" name="imonth" onchange="Calendars.monthNavigation(this.value)">
<option value="5,2016" selected="selected">May 2016</option>
<option value="6,2016">June 2016</option>
<option value="7,2016">July 2016</option>
<option value="8,2016">August 2016</option>
<option value="9,2016">September 2016</option>
<option value="10,2016">October 2016</option>
</select>
</div>

<div class="client_form">
<label>Select Your Name</label>
<select id="client_name" name="client_name" required>
<option value='' > - Select Name - </option>
<option value="26">Michael</option>
<option value="27">David</option>
<option value="32">Samuel</option>
</select>
</div>
```

In the original file, Select name box code is written like the following:

```
<select id="client_name" name="client_name" required onchange="showclient(this.value);">
<option value=''> - Select Name - </option>
<?php
foreach($clients AS $client){
?>
<option value="<?php echo $client->id;?>"><?php echo $client->first_name.' '.$client->last_name;?></option>
<?php
}
?>
</select>
```

And the script that I have tried to hold that Select Name box value:

```
<script>
function showclient(client)
{
if(client=='')
{       
    document.getElementById("client_name").style.display="block";
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("client_name");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        x[i].style.display="none";
    }
}
}
</script>
```

I really don't know whether this kind of information is enough or not to address my issue. Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Comment: From what I understand, the problem is that when you change the Month select box it also changes the Name select box. Is that right?

Comment: @MeltingDog yes, exactly. And I want a separate script only for Name select box so that whatever happen in Month select box, name select box value won't change.

Comment: Then you are going about this the wrong way. Select boxes act independently of each other, anyway. There is probably a script in your code that is altering the way all of them behave. You need to look for that -  it's not proper coding to just write more code over the top of it - you'll end up creating more problems in the future.

Try looking for some JS or JQuery that selects all `<select>` elements.

We cannot really help without seeing your site or JS in its entirety.